# Why is an affine translation said to be a shear in a higher dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations

I was doing a little refresher on matrix transformations, and started reading on affine transformations. After a while I kind of understood the purpose of utilizing 3x3 matrices for 2D transformations, but then I stumbled upon the affine transformation matrix for a translation:

[image: affine translation transformation]

Some of the sources I have found mention that what this is doing is basically performing a shear of the point in 3D space along the plane $z = 1$ (at least for this case of 2D transformations), but even after watching videos demonstrating what's happening underneath (like [this excellent one on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Augmented_matrix)), I can't quite understand how that matrix is a meant to represent a shear of any sort, let alone one in 3D.

PS: I'm more accustomed to the simple shear transformation of the likes of $
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & h_x\\
h_y & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$, so I'm not very knowledgeable of the forms they can take and that may be the cause of my confusion.

Comment: What do you think a shear in three dimensions ought to look like? For that matter, what should a shear look like in two dimensions? (The "shear" matrix you showed is not necessarily what I understand to be a shear; in fact I think it fair to say it is only very rarely a shear.)

Comment: @DavidK I see what you mean now. In truth, I may have made a lapse of judgement on my part in the sense that I thought that mixing the standard forms for horizontal and vertical shears like that would work. It seems I had forgotten the proper definition of a shear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your transformation looks like this.
$$
x'=x+t_xz;\quad y'=y+t_yz,\quad z'=z
$$
First of all, points move horizontally, since the $z$ is preserved. Also, observe that $(x,y)$ becomes $(x,y)+z(t_x,t_y)$ which means, for any fixed $z$ a translation  by the (horizontal) vector $z(t_x,t_y,0)$ which keeps its direction and has a length, proportional to $z$. That is exactly what a shear is: a translation on each plane parallel to $z$ by a vector, proportional to $z$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! In reality, I had forgotten that a "shear" was defined as such, so I had a bit of trouble making sense of it in my head. Thinking of it as just a way of representing the operation $(x,y) + z(t_x, t_y)$ (with $z$ being $1$ in this case) as a matrix multiplication made it much clearer.